# Using wildcard in bash loop array

Tags: bash, loops, rsync

I've got a collection of hundreds of directories ordered in alphabetical order and with differently named files inside. These directories I want to copy over to another location using `rsync`. 
I don't wanna go over all the directories manually, but instead I want to use the `--include` option of `rsync` or create a loop in `bash` to go over the directories.

For far I've tried using the `bash` script below, but had no success yet.

```
for dir in {A..Z}; do
  echo "$dir";
  rsync --progress --include $dir'*' --exclude '*' -rt -e ssh username@192.168.1.123:/source/directory/ ~/target/directory/
done;
```

Does anyone know what would be the correct way to go over the directories using `rsync`'s `--include` option?

**Update:**
The `bash` script above was more to try out the loop to go over my directories and see what comes out. The command I actually wanted to use was this one:

```
for dir in /*; do
  rsync --progress --include $dir'*' --exclude '*' --bwlimit=2000 -rt -e ssh username@192.168.1.123:/source/directory/ ~/target/directory/
done;
```

I know `bash` can do something like `{A..Z}`, but this doesn't seem to get me the result I want. I already copied half of the alphabet of directories so I was trying `{F..Z}` as an array.

**Update**

I've come up with the following script to run from my source directories location.

```
#!/bin/bash

time=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # For time indication
dir=/source/directory/[P-Z]* # Array of directories with name starting with "P" to "Z"

printf "[$time] Transferring: /source/directory/\"$dir\"\n"
rsync -trP  -e 'ssh -p 123' --bwlimit=2000 $dir username@192.168.1.123:/target/directory
```

This will transfer all directories from the source directory with names starting with character "P" to "Z" over ssh using port 123.
This works for me in a shell script. I'm sure there are better ways to do this in a single line command, but this one I just came up with to help myself out.

Comment: You should use `"$dir"` in the command line, but since you don't show the `rsync` command you're trying to use, we can't tell you what you're doing wrong very easily, can we?  (Or, the limit of what we can tell you is "You've misspelled `rsync`; it is not spelled `ls` — and the `--include` option is missing".)

Comment: Mr.Mark, could you please change the title to reflect your intent and clarify what you want to know (title = bash wildcard vs. subject = rsync include confuses me)?

Comment: Updated with the example of `rsync` command I'm using. Any ideas with this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the following script to run from my source directories location.

```
#!/bin/bash

time=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # For time indication
dir=/source/directory/[P-Z]* # Array of directories with name starting with "P" to "Z"

printf "[$time] Transferring: /source/directory/\"$dir\"\n"
rsync -trP  -e 'ssh -p 123' --bwlimit=2000 $dir username@192.168.1.123:/target/directory
```

This will transfer all directories from the source directory with names starting with character "P" to "Z" over ssh using port 123. This works for me in a shell script. I'm sure there are better ways to do this in a single line command, but this one I just came up with to help myself out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want recursive `rsync`. I'd go with:

`rsync -r / --restOfYourRsyncArgs`

That walks over every file/folder/subfolder in `/` (could be A LOT, consider excludes and/or a different target path) and uploads/downloads. Set excludes for files and folders you don't want sent.

Comment: This would be the initial approach I wanted to take, but I needed a bit more flexible solution. I posted my final script in the question post.